# Get Array Serialize Jquery To PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want get data from ajax (jquery) to PHP.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
     var slider_item = $('.slider .owl-page');
    if(slider_item.hasClass('active')){
        var attr_color = slider_item.attr('color');
    }
    var th = $('#form').serializeArray();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://cute-tube.s-host.net/form.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {"serialize": th, "color": attr_color},
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

    });
```

I have in Form Data this one:

```
serialize[0][name]:name
<br>
serialize[0][value]:Nck
<br>
serialize[1][name]:phone
<br>
serialize[1][value]:+7 (123) 123-12-31
<br>
color:kosmosfiolet
```

And via PHP I might send value in mail

---

I tried get arrray Data in PHP

```
$data_content = $_POST['serialize'];

$data = json_decode($data_content);

$name_send = json_decode($name); //Nick

$phone_send = json_decode($phone); //123123123
```

---

Please help me send data in mail php.

Thank's!

Comment: What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I don't know What i Might to use to get this array from ajax) in PHP ofcourse
I wanna get data in PHP and send name and phone after some decode to mail function

Comment: See the example at the [bottom of this page](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: emm, it's not help me( I might to know, how get serialize[0][value]:Nck
from js to save it in variable and send to mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sent that data to your mail right?

Here use the mail function (if mail() is enabled on your server)

I have no idea why you want to send the phone number and name seperately.

However assuming they all contain different data

```
<?php

$admin_email = "youremail@";
$subject = "Subject";
$email = "Sendersemail@";

// sending data
$data_content = addslashes($_POST['serialize']);
$data = json_decode($data_content); 

//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $data , "From:" . $email);

// sending name
$name_send = json_decode($name); //Nick

//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $name_send, "From:" . $email);

// sending phone
$phone_send = json_decode($phone); //123123123
//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $phone_send, "From:" . $email);

?>
```

Comment: I tried to send all data in message but it's not working)

Comment: Can you please help me in skype? nickolay.kuzmin1

Comment: No skype sorry. Does your jquery create the data properly? you can check if everything is ok by printing out the $_POST['serialize'] var by using print_r( $_POST['serialize']); if that data is fine everything should be fine. Can you let me know what exactly is happening?

Comment: Look, in Jquery I use serializeArray()  and my data ajax look something like this - data: {"serialize": th, "color": attr_color}

In PHP I might get serialize data from ajax )) I tried :

$data_content = addslashes($_POST['serialize']);
$data = json_decode($data_content); 

and send $data to mail example: mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $data, $headers);
But not sent me it in mail) empty blank 

And I can't test var_dump php $_POST['serialize'] because when visit my php link there - NULL

Comment: Which browser do you use? if using chrome right click on the form page and start inspector, inside inspector go to network, now send your form you will see the network activity there. click on the php filename and see the response, this is where you will be able to see the output of your vardump, and BTW the vardump command is wrong, it is vardump(array); or use print_r(array);